# Exception initializing Emgu.CV

Tags: vb.net, ocr, emgucv

Hey this is my first time using this website, but I a problem. I saw this awesome youtube video about getting ocr to work with vb.net. Here the url:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjdu8SjEtG0

So I decided to download the emgu libraries, here the url:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/

I did everything the video say and I get this error: "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract' threw an exception."

I even copy the exception(if that do any help):

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract' threw an exception.
  Source=WindowsApplication1
  StackTrace:
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form1()
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Users\UltimateSoul\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
       Message=The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract' threw an exception.
       Source=Emgu.CV.OCR
       TypeName=Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract
       StackTrace:
            at Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract..ctor(String dataPath, String language, OcrEngineMode mode)
            at WindowsApplication1.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\UltimateSoul\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 8
       InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
            Message=The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
            Source=Emgu.CV
            TypeName=Emgu.CV.CvInvoke
            StackTrace:
                 at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CV_MAKETYPE(Int32 depth, Int32 cn)
                 at Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract..cctor()
            InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
                 Message=Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
                 Source=Emgu.CV
                 TypeName=""
                 StackTrace:
                      at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvRedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr prevUserdata)
                      at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
                 InnerException:
```

I been on this for days, and got no where. Please help thanks!

I sorry here the code

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.OCR
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Public Class Form1

    Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)
    Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X + 4, Me.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y + 30), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)
        PictureBox1.Image = pic

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic))
        RichTextBox1.Text = OCRz.GetText

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to post the code where you initialize the object. We can't guess at how you do this.

Comment: youtube 'tutorials' are in most cases not a really good source for working code ;) you might better start in the emgu wiki and use the tutorial provided there: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial

Comment: alright I check it out wiki, by the way here the code:

Comment: alright and thanks!, I check wiki, but anybody could help me with this problem. I appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception. ? Topic 1.4?

Comment: btw, from your exception: `Message=Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`. Not in the project folder?

Comment: It is in the project folder, it is still giving me errors

Answer (score 1):

copy `cvextern.dll` and file with `opencv_**.dll` to your output directory: `bin/Debug/`

Setting your configuration manager to run "AnyCPU", and the configuration must "Debug".

Comment: Please include sources and explain your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a 64bit OS, you must add to reference the following files too (For EMGU CV version >=2.4)

`cudart64_42_9.dll, cvextern.dll, npp64_42_9.dll`

This will help in using emguCv 2.4.x in 64bit OS without internal exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In the video it is x64 dir being copied.
Instead copy x86 dir in your project dir
and in properties select all the dll files
enable 'copy if newer'.