# Nvidia: the graphic driver could not find compatible graphic hardware

Tags: emgucv

I can't install the nvidia installation in cuda toolkit. I don't have a nvidia card. Does that means I can't use emgu.cv? I been on this all yesterday and emgu.cv is still giving me problems.

Here the link that still shows my problem:
[Exception initializing Emgu.CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417449/exception-initializing-emgu-cv)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can. Run the installer. Then go to the directory where it has unzipped all the files and choose nvcuda.dl_ and using command prompt expand it into nvcuda.dll.
Place this dll in system32 folder.
This should solve the 'nvcuda.dll not found' error.